# what is the impact on Kafka topic partitions log when consumed using multiple Consumer groups?

Tags: apache-kafka

My question is more related to **performance** rather than how they consume data in consumer groups.
We know that kafka create single PARTITION LOG on filesystem, which is accessed by all consumer group's consumer on that partition.

***What will be the impact on accessing that PARTITION LOG file by multiple consumers from different consumer's group?***

1. Increasing the consumer groups for a specific partition log will slow down accessing that partition or not?
2. How Kafka handles such concurrent file read I/Os on a single
   partition log from multiple consumer groups to same parition?

Comment: Kafka should be able to scale to hundreds if not thousands of clients for the same partition. If you really want to to know "how", the code is open source. Impacts include open file handles, disk IO, and network saturation

Comment: but as answered below from Kafka 2.4 "From Kafka 2.4, Kafka consumers can fetch data from closest follower replicas as well which means that if your partition is replicated across different brokers, then different consumers belonging to different consumer groups consuming the same partition can be served by different brokers thus reducing the load on your leader broker". 
Then shall we restrict consumer groups ?

Comment: Why would you want to restrict them? Implementing restrictions via quotas will reduce IO at the expense of slower consumers

Answer (score 0):

1. Kafka uses memory-mapped files so reads typically *should* be served from the memory rather than from the disk.
2. From Kafka 2.4, Kafka consumers can fetch data from closest follower replicas as well which means that **if your partition is replicated** across different brokers, then different consumers belonging to different consumer groups consuming the same partition can be served by different brokers thus reducing the load on your leader broker.
3. In previous versions of Kafka, if multiple consumer groups start consuming messages from the same partition and since that partition leader is responsible for serving those read requests, you can observe some slowness and this is due to several factors including your hardware, OS etc.
4. Also note that partitions are divided into segments in Kafka where each segment is a file on the disk in the partition directory. Different consumers may be consuming different segments of the same partition.

Comment: That makes sense, I am using 0.10.2.x version. So in broader term are we discouraging use of Consumer groups then, as multiple consumer group consuming on same partition will definitely slow down partition consumption ?

Comment: You need not "discourage" multiple consumer groups "just because" it slows down partition consumption since consumer groups are meant for different use-case, reduce consumer groups only if it doesn't effect your design badly, otherwise you might want to look at enhancing your broker hardware, upgrading kafka, adding more brokers etc as feasible.